# Transaction stuck since yesterday

Tags: parity, pending-transactions, ropsten

I'm on Ropsten network and since yesterday I did a transaction with 5 039 400 Gas and now all my transactions are in status pending. But with another account I can make a transaction to this stuck account.

Someone can explain to me what is wrong ?